# What is the etymology of the Maghrebi interjection "شاه" (chah or cheh)?

Tags: etymology, arabic, berber

At least in the Maghreb, there is a word to say "serves [somebody] right!", i.e. "!شاه" or *"ccah!"* in Berber form.

I'm struggling to find its etymology. Although it might be Arabic or Berber, the reference Kabyle-French dictionary *[Parler des At Mangellat, II](https://books.google.fr/books?id=nZdP85wiDmcC)* (in french) reports this word and links it to the root `C-H`, without mentioning any Arabic origin or an etymology. Thus, it might a Berber root.

Are there some information about it?

Comment: Though I know absolutely nothing about Maghreb or Berber, _chah!_ sounds **extremely** like a simple interjection, like _bah_ or _meh_ or _pfft_ in English. It wouldn’t surprise me in the slightest if this has no real ‘etymology’ but is just a primitive exclamation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, it may be an explanation, indeed.

Comment: It sounds to me like *šā’ahu* = “he (God) willed it”.  Just a guess.

Comment: @BertBarrois, interesting, haven't thought of that.

Comment: I know nothing about Maghreb but in Persian شاه means king and it is not chah or cheh it is Shaah ;)

Comment: @Amir, you've missed the diacritic over the shin.

Answer (score 0):

In Algerian, the word شاه means "what", usually interchangeable with واش. For example, شاه قلت؟ means "What did you say?", or شاه هذا؟ "What is this?". It is common to use it as an interjection, شاه؟, which is best translated as "What?". I have not heard it used to mean "serves them right", but I have not lived in Algeria for long.

I'm not sure about its etymology. It might come from واش, which comes from وأي شيء (and which thing).

Comment: "Cheh!" or expressions like "cheh fik!" ("serves you right", "bien fait !" in french) are pretty common in Algeria and in the Maghreb.